# implementation of stacks in java

Tags: java

I have to implement in java some stack`s functions,and chose an exercise to resolve,for example,insert a new element in the end of the stack without break the order. How  can I do this?

```
// stack.java
// demonstrates stacks
// to run this program: C>java StackApp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Stack
{
  private int maxSize; // size of stack array
  private long[] stackArray;
  private int top; // top of stack
//--------------------------------------------------------------
  public Stack(int s) // constructor
 {
    maxSize = s; // set array size
    stackArray = new long[maxSize]; // create array
    top = -1; // no items yet
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public void makeEmpty( ) {
    top = -1;
    }

   public void push(long j) // put item on top of stack 
   {
     stackArray[++top] = j; // increment top, insert item
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public long pop() // take item from top of stack
 { return stackArray[top--]; // access item, decrement top
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------

   public long peek() // peek at top of stack
  { return stackArray[top];
   }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isEmpty() // true if stack is empty
   {return (top == -1);
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isFull() // true if stack is full
    {return (top == maxSize-1);
     }
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
 // end class StackX
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) Also, by "end of the stack" do you mean pushing? Or putting it as the first element? Because that's not really how a stack is supposed to function.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your idea on how this *could* work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Do you need to implement it on your own? Or are you looking for an API? Java has a stack-ish Deque http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Comment: We won't give you a whole answer, you have to show some effort, too. Read about Stacks, Queues, Linked lists, ArrayLists, possibly even Binary trees, too. They all use some parts of what you might want to use. When you have an idea about what you want to do and how, try it and come back with a particular problem. If you're looking for a done class, use [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html).

Comment: http://www.jeggu.com/2010/04/implementation-of-stack-in-java-java.html

Comment: 'Some stack's functions'? Which ones?

Comment: yes it is a home work,up there is the code of the functions,,now I have to use this functions in an exercise,such as inserting a new element in the stack not as the last element,but the first without breaking the order,

Answer (score 4):

There are pre-built `Stack` classes in the JVM libraries; however, if you are doing this as a lesson in creating your own stacks, there is an easy way to do this with a single-linked list.

You will need two classes, a `Stack` class which will present the `void push(Object)`, `Object pop()` and whatever methods, and a `Node` class which will represent the nodes in the linked list.

Maintain one member variable in the `Stack` for the list's head, and one member variable in the `Stack` for the list's tail.  Pushing an `Object` onto the stack will require a new `Node` to hold the object, so the `Node` will need a "data" member to reference the pushed `Object`, and a "next" reference to the "next" `Node`.

The rest of the pushing problem is just adding elements to the chain of nodes by crating a new `Node`, having it reference the pushed object, pointing it's next node member to the current tail, and updating the `Stack`'s current tail reference.  Popping will return the Object referenced by the `Stack`s tail's `Node`, and will update the tail to point to the "next" `Node`.

There are special cases to consider, but they are not difficult.  Basically you need to take care when pushing on an empty `Stack` and when popping would yeild an empty `Stack`.

After doing all of this, you can easily add `peek()` methods and such if you like.